# If a color is reflected by a non-reflective coating, what happens to that color light in the film?

Tags: optics, interference, geometric-optics

If an anti-reflective coating appears to have a green tint, what does this say about incident white light when it is inside the film?

Apparently, green light is diminished inside the film, but I can't find an explanation as to why. What happens to red and blue light - are they amplified?

Answer (score 0):

This question can easily be Googled, for example: http://www.edu.pe.ca/gray/class_pages/krcutcliffe/physics521/16light/definitions/16definitions%20colors%20in%20thin%20films.htm 
Depending on the material (glass, crystal etc) the reflected colors will depend on a combination of the materials thickness and photon frequency. Sometimes the thickness varies as with an oil slick and you get multiple colors as the different frequency photons interfere. As for your first question, white light is made of photons with frequencies across the spectrum and they all enter the material but at just the right thickness green light is reflected.

Comment: On that website it says "Remember, every color of light has a different frequency and therefore a different wavelength. This means that only one color of light can constructively interfere at any given thickness of soap film. So only one color could get brighter while all other colors would get dimmer or completely cancelled out." If this is the case, if green tint is observed on the film, why is it that green light is diminished? Shouldn't all the other colors be diminished whereas green is amplified due to constructive interference?